# Sony Z Ultra Google Play Edition Crash when Uninstalling

Tags: google-play-store, sync, crashes, uninstallation, sony-xperia-z

I decided to move from Verizon Samsung Note 2 to a T-Mobile [Sony Z Ultra Google Play Edition](https://play.google.com/store/devices/details?id=sony_z_ultra).

When I logged in to my new phone, all my apps (including Verizon undeletable crapware) synced through my Google account into my new phone. But, since these were not system apps but user apps in my new phone, I happily clicked the "uninstall" button (on my Note 2, I only saw "disable" but no uninstall options for the bloatwares) and my phone immediately crashed and restarted!

Now, my phone crashes everytime I try to uninstall ANY apps (even new ones I just installed)! So I just have a uninstall folder containing my old Verizon crapwares and some other apps I want to uninstall now.

How can I fix this so I can uninstall without rebooting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not alone. Inability to uninstall any apps and crashes in Settings, are some of the nasty bugs in Sony's recent Google Play edition devices. Currently there are no workarounds, and you must wait until Sony releases an update with fixes for these issues.

Sources: [Android Authority](http://www.androidauthority.com/sony-z-ultra-gpe-bug-324916/), [Android Community](http://androidcommunity.com/sony-z-ultra-google-play-edition-bugs-hindering-usage-20131216/)

[Edit]
Allegedly, the [upcoming](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/12/16/sony-z-ultra-gpe-bugs-preventing-access-to-security-settings-and-uninstalling-apps-google-is-aware-and-working-on-a-fix/) 4.4.2 OTA update will fix most of the glaring issues.

[Edit 2]
[Confirmed](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/12/17/sony-z-ultra-gpe-ota-to-android-4-4-2kot49h-incoming-fixes-major-bugs/), the just released 4.4.2 OTA update fixes those nasty bugs on the Z Ultra.  Check to see if you have it (keep in mind it's probably a staged roll-out, so you might not see the update immediately.)

Comment: This seems to be a bug in many Android 4.4 ROMS also, the devs have ironed them out in some cases, and flashing alternative GApps helps also, but if you aren't rooted, or intend on rooting you will indeed have to wait for Sony to get their act together and release new firmware. Kitkat is buggy in general as the quick release of 4.4, 4.4.1 and 4.4.2 would indicate, there are bugs in a few areas and this is one of the nastier ones. Random Reboots of the phone (RR) are becoming common on S4 Google Edition also.

Comment: Google and Sony are reportedly working hard to release the 4.4.2 OTA for their GPe devices that should fix these bugs. My GS4 GPe has not had these problems on stock 4.4 (or .1, or .2.)  It's possible that people reporting random reboots are trying out the new ART runtime, instead of the recommended Dalvik. Google said that ART is not yet ready for prime time, and is a tool for developers' testing at this point.

Comment: 4.4.2 for the Z Ultra was just released which is supposed to fix these issues.

Comment: It happens in the ROMs on ART and Dalvik (odexed and Deodexed). ART is causing issues all of its own without this extra issue, but as you say it's Beta at best at the moment. 4.4.2 has just been released, and hopefully the issue will be fixed!